# How to get Jenkins to show skipped tests using email-ext?

Tags: junit, jenkins, email-ext

I am using email-ext plugin within Jenkins to display passed failed, and the email has a nice blue for passed methods and red for failed. What it is not including is the Ignored tests within a class. Shouldn't the annotations for Junit's @Ignore display as skipped in the junit results via email-ext?

I am using the html_gmail template like so: ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html_gmail"}

and I am using the following tokens in the extendable email notificatin config:

Total Amount of Tests:
${TEST_COUNTS, var}

Total = $TEST_COUNTS
Failed = ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}

Total = $TEST_COUNTS
Passed = ${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"}

Is there an: Ignore = ${TEST_COUNTS,var=skipped")   ????

Comment: The doc says: `${TEST_COUNTS, var}` displays the number of tests.
`var` Defaults to "total".
`total` the number of all tests.
`pass` the number of passed tests.
`fail` the number of failed tests.
`skip` the number of skipped tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -

```
${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"}
```

Take a look at the source code of [TestCountsContent.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/TestCountsContent.java)